# Is it possible to connect a database to LaTeX to produce data-driven documents?

Tags: database

I'm starting to write a LaTeX-based reference manual, and have realised that a lot of my needs could be solved by writing a database and then producing the reference manual from that. Lots of my pages will be exactly the same, with slightly different information in them.

Is there a way to link LaTeX to a database, in a similar way to Database Report engines do - so that I can, for example, create a page per record in the database, including each field in different locations on the page?

Comment: Have you considered writing a script (e.g., in Python or Perl) that reads the database and outputs Latex source code?

Comment: See detailed walkthrough for Lua and SQLite [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491057/3406).This approach still works as of September 2021, but may not be futureproof. This example should be trivially adaptable for other DBs that LuaSQL supports.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may try [latexdb](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexdb). It connects LaTeX to a MySQL database.

Comment: How does it work with MariaDB?

Answer (score 14):

You might want to check the answers to these questions:

- [File input and output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2375/627);
- [Tool for manipulating LaTeX tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1801/627);
- [Is anybody using TeX for business reporting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3506/627)

Depending on what you want to do, you could look into the [datatool package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) or pgfplotstable. Or if your needs are more complex (tex is not the most efficient language for doing sophisticated database manipulation), you should write a script to produce a latex formatted report directly from the database (as Jukka suggested).

Answer (score 8):

Latexdb is a great idea, but works only with MySQL.

I have written a clone, first in Ruby, recently in .Net (works with Mono, too), with some nice improvements. See http://www.hoens.net/robin/nlatexdb

Answer (score 5):

You can load dynamic libraries into Luatex, like the [Lua-SQL database bridge](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/index.html).  I've never done this kind of thing, mind, but there are people here who would know how to do this.

You can invoke Lua from Tex with appropriate directive, such as from [Lualatex](http://www.luatex.de/tag/lualatex/), to pull and process data from the database bridge.

Answer (score 5):

I'd write some script to extract the data in XML format (perhaps the database already offers that?) and process the file directly with ConTeXt. ConTeXt is well suited for a) reading XML input (directly) and b) for generating datasheets or alike. For example ConTeXt now offers `\asciimode` that makes most funny characters normal (&,#,~,$), so don't have to deal with escaping characters beyond `%` `{` `}` and `\`.

Comment: I made a simple xml database. (See here [link] http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45114/could-i-insert-the-elements-of-a-mdb-or-csv-base-in-latex). Is it possible to write a simple ConTeXt(LuaLaTex) or LuaLaTeX code for this xml to illustrate your answer?

Comment: @kornaros you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Sweave and R](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming each record has at most 9 fields, then one possibility would be to define a macro like

```
\newcommand\handlerecord[8]{...}
```

and then write a script as Jukka Suomela suggested that basically writes out the preamble and then a bunch of `\handlerecord{field1}{field2}...` and ends it off with an `\end{document}`.

If you have more than 9 fields, you can use any of the answers to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2132/647) to define the `\handlerecord` macro.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [DataTeX](https://github.com/CSMathematics/DataTex). A short [description](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331594/using-an-exercises-package-to-build-lots-of-math-calculus-exercise-lists-and-tes/332025#332025).

Comment: Great idea. Any update regarding Windows users ? I have the same (idea...) type of file management system but on Excel :) your DataTeX looks stunning

Comment: @JeT I can say that DataTex is 99% ready for windows use. The only things that keeps me back is that I can't compile the project on windows due to some bug on the pdf viewer. I'm working on it and I hope to fix it soon. Thanks.

Comment: I'll use it for sure. From what I see (screenshots) we reach the same conclusions about how indicng things on top of the latex file organisation. ευχαριστώ !

Comment: Παρακαλώ (You're welcome)!

Comment: If I may, take a look at this [answer](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1348) and this [one](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1466). It enables to use pgfkeys based on your document naming to compile selectively group of documents. It seems consistent with your system.

Comment: It looks very interesting! I will have to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

you can make a .tex file with only data and keyword where your data is stored

"database.tex" for instance, contains the assignation of the variable \DataKeyWord and \MultipleDataKeyWord:

```
\DataKeyWord{my data}
\MultipleDataKeyWord{Belle}{journ\'ee}
```

In a layout.sty file, you declare your variable:

```
\def\DataKeyWord#1{\gdef\@DataKeyWord{#1}}
\def\MultipleDataKeyWord#1#2{\gdef\@FirstDataKeyWord{#1}\gdef\@SecondDataKeyWord{#2}}
```

when you want to use this in your layout.sty file, use the command:

```
\newcommand{\CommandNameLikeWriteMySection}{
My Data is \@DataKeyWord
I wish you a "\@FirstDataKeyWord \@SecondDataKeyWord"}
```

then in your MySection.tex file used to write your report, you will use the command:

```
\CommandNameLikeWriteMySection
```

and it will execute the printing of the command \CommandNameLikeWriteMySection to write your pdf

Comment: The problem of this method is that it hard to compare 2 database files and make a table to compare data back to back because the value will be assign first and then print.

Answer (score 0):

See here as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40728/4736

The answer refers to a template engine called jinja, nowadays jinja2. There are some answers in the realms of the internet about LaTeX and jinja2, see here https://tug.org/tug2019/slides/slides-ziegenhagen-python.pdf e.g.

I recently used python and jinja2 to produce lots of *.tex files.

Hey, this is my first answer to a question more than a decade later than the question has been posted.