# Sourcing data from a CSV to make a pretty report

Tags: templates

Can I achieve like this one using LaTeX?

[sample_report](http://i1226.photobucket.com/albums/ee404/teezdumk/bitmap.jpg)

And here is the condition:

- All Chart are already provided in `pdf` or `svg` format
- Other data will be dynamically loaded from `csv` file (all of them are tabular data)

All I need to do is make the layout for the `chart` and `tabular data` like this one.

Thank You.

Comment: For creating reports like this in LaTeX, including the diagrams and tables, I can recommend using [R](http://www.r-project.org/) in combination with [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/) and [xtable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html).

Comment: Can you achieve this: yes, absolutely. The question is whether LaTeX is the best solution here.

Comment: @Konrad: What might be a better solution?

Comment: @ipavlic Sorry for that incomplete comment: I’ve heard that ConTeXt has better control over layout boxes of a page than LaTeX.

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3697/627)

Comment: @teezdumk: I think that all of the items in the linked page _can_ be done, although perhaps not that easily. I wonder what exactly you need in an answer here. It all seems to come down to placing appropriate boxes and loading the data using something like `datatool`.

Comment: Does anyone else get the feeling that this is 'not a real question': I'm not sure what a good answer could actually say.

Comment: I'm closing on the basis of 'not a real question', as it is not clear what a good answer would really include. Of course, if I'm wrong then vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/) if you're familiar with Python.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with LaTeX?