# Could I insert the elements of a mdb or csv base in Latex?

Tags: database

I want to insert some information from a csv text file or from a mdb (MS data base) base into a latex document. For example I have a document  with math exercises and I would like to insert the first and the second element (i.e. exercise) of the base into `\begin{enumerate} \end{enumerate}`. How could this achieved in LaTeX?

Comment: Have you tried `datatool` package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `etoolbox` has `\docsvlist` and `\forcsvlist`. The documentation for the `\docsvlist` gives the following example:

```
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1}
\docsvlist{item1, item2, {item3a, item3b}, item4}
\end{itemize}
```

If you wanted to stop the list at 2 items, you could use a counter

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
      \newcounter{item}
      \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
        \ifnumless{\arabic{item}}{2}{\item #1}{}
        \stepcounter{item}}%
      \docsvlist{item1, item2, {item3a, item3b}, item4}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think \docsvist is a good idea. One more question: Let us suppose we have the  \docsvlist{item1, item2, {item3a, item3b,item3c, item3d}, item4} and someone wants to take only the 
item3b and item3d for use with \do command(see Daniels Shub' answer). How this could be achieved??

Comment: @kornaros This is really a new question, and I think it should be asked as such. I think you will need to provide additional information to get an answer. Specifically, what do you know in advance and what do you expect the user to input.