# Valuable texcount implementation seems to conflict with titlesec package

Tags: titlesec, texcount

The inset texcount implementation seems to conflict with `titlesec` package.

The desired outcome is to relieve the conflict with `titlesec` as well as ensuring robustness against other potential conflicts.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{filecontents}%
%\usepackage{titlesec} %**** uncomment to see error message


% Compile with  --enable-write18 or --shell-escape options   
\immediate\write18{texcount -char -merge -tex -sum \jobname.tex | grep -i section > \jobname Count.txt} % counts characters
%\immediate\write18{texcount -merge -tex -sum \jobname.tex | grep -i section > \jobname Count.txt} % counts words
\newcommand{\limitcount}{-1}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newcommand{\processCount}{%
 \newread\counts
 \def\zpar{\par}
 \openin\counts=\jobname Count.txt
 \loop
 \read\counts to \sectioncount
 \ifx\sectioncount\zpar\else
 \showcount{\sectioncount}\\
 \fi
 \ifeof\counts
 \else
 \repeat
}

\newcommand*{\showcount}[1]{%
 % e.g. 67+18+0 (1/0/0/0) S[ubs]ection: The first subsection
 \StrBehind{#1}{ection: }[\sectiontitleplusspace]
 \StrGobbleRight{\sectiontitleplusspace}{1}[\sectiontitle]
 \StrBefore{#1}{+}[\thiscount]
 \expandafter\ifcsname\sectiontitle limit\endcsname%
  \renewcommand{\limitcount}{\csname\sectiontitle limit\endcsname}%
 \else%
  \renewcommand{\limitcount}{-1}%
 \fi%
 \sectiontitle:
 {%
  \ifthenelse{\thiscount>\limitcount}{%
   \textcolor{red}{\thiscount/\limitcount}%
   \ifthenelse{\limitcount>-1}{%
    \ (over by \number\numexpr\thiscount-\limitcount\relax)%
   }{}%
  }{%
   \textcolor{green}{\thiscount/\limitcount}%
  }%
 }
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\contentlimit}[1]{%
 \expandafter\newcommand\csname\@currentlabelname limit\endcsname{#1}
}
\makeatother
     

\begin{filecontents*}{texcountinc.tex}
\subsection*{Input section title}
\contentlimit{40}
HEy, here are some more characters.
File contents that will get input elsewhere. $a^2+b^2=c^2$.
\[\frac{\sin A}a=\frac{\sin B}b=\frac{\sin C}c\]
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

%TC:ignore

\section*{Introduction}
\contentlimit{2000}

Content for section which has become longer and longer

%TC:endignore


\section*{Another section with subsections over limit}
\contentlimit{15}

Intro

\subsection*{The first subsection no stated limit}

This subsection has somewhat more voluminous content which tends to go on and on... and on

\subsection*{Extra spaces ignored  }
\contentlimit{50}

Content aimed at testing whether math and symbols are counted: $\int$, $\Sigma$.


\section*{texcount doesn't understand lipsum}
\contentlimit{1}

Another input

\subsection*{Inputing Content}
\contentlimit{18}

\input{texcountinc}

%TC:ignore 

\section*{An ignored section}

This section is ignored


% display information on document
\newpage
\section*{Count}
\processCount

%TC:endignore 

\end{document}
```

See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527602/simplified-texcount-results-display) for background.

Comment: It turns out it's exactly that problem, and can use exactly that solution.  I did spend some time trying to use `\IfSubStr` to skip the need for grep, but I couldn't get the macro to handle the line containing `#`.  And I spent some time trying to use `catchfile` instead of the manual reading, but I couldn't figure out how to go through the results line by line.  Either of those would make the original process better.  But this should at least get you back to working.

Comment: Removing the `*` from `\section*` and `\subsection*` works! (I am assuming that this is the proposed workaround).  Including the patch proposed in the linked question also works - the `*` functionality is negated.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that's what happened.  The proposed workaround adds a `\def` to your preamble to that effect though.

Comment: After updating MiKTeX, this mwe no longer compiles on my system.

Comment: @Teepeemm, above you write: "The proposed workaround adds a `\def` to your preamble".  Did you post this workaround in another issue?

Comment: I think I was referring to the accepted answer of the duplicate.