# Autoinclude files

Tags: templates, include

In my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61746/template-which-can-change) I asked about templates. I got quite a cool answer, thanks!

There is code like

```
\long\def\FourierIntroduction{Content}
```

In say the file `Fourier.tex`. What I would like is that if I include `Fourier.tex` that my template (which I made beforehand) takes these comments (if they exist) as data to produce the required document.

Hence, say I do `\include{Fourier}` in my main document (of course, perhaps `include` needs to be modified), then this document is opened and searched for commands like `\FourierIntroduction` and such (I would name the first part after the file itself to avoid collisions, or could this not happen?). If found, the template should execute:

```
\section{Introduction}
\FourierIntroduction
```

In such a way that I can modify the order of my template, rerun my document and get excellent result. Any suggestions how to approach this puzzle?

**Edit:** I have looked around on this website and have found a suggestion to use `filehook` by one of our moderators. I wonder if this is a good way to go:

```
\usepackage{filehook}
\usepackage{currfile}

\def\Introduction{Introduction}

\AtEndOfEveryFile{%
  \section{\currfilebase}%
  \subsection{Introduction}%
  \csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname%
}
```

**Edit #2:** I have tried to implement "environment" and as suspected: I failed. I have the follow minimal-non-working-example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{filehook}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{comment}

\def\Introduction{Introduction}
\def\Methods{Methods}

\NewEnviron{introduction}{%
  \long\def{\csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname}{\BODY}%
}%

\AtEndOfEveryFile{%
  \section{\currfilebase}%
  \subsection{Introduction}%
  \csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname%
  \subsection{Methods}%
  \csname \currfilebase \Methods \endcsname%
}%


\begin{document}

\include{Fourier}

\end{document}
```

And `Fourier.tex` contains stuff like:

```
\begin{introduction}
  <TEST>
\end{introduction}

\long\def\FourierMethods{Test TWO}
```

I hope that the "example" is making clear what my goal is.

**Edit #3:** Thanks to canaaerus I now know that I should "expand". So, I should replace

```
\NewEnviron{introduction}{%
      \long\def{\csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname}{\BODY}%
    }%
```

With

```
\NewEnviron{introduction}{%
  \expandafter\long\expandafter\xdef\csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname{\BODY}%
}%
```

But apparently that messes up `amsmath` and `amsthm` environments. For example if I have the file `Fourier.tex` and I `\include{Fourier}` I get an error when I have this in my `Fourier.tex`:

```
\begin{introduction}
  \begin{theorem}
    Test: $f$.
  \end{theorem}
  More.
\end{introduction}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where the `\FourierIntroduction` command should be executed?

Comment: Have a look at [Automating error message references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59621/automating-error-message-references). I am using that method for a very similar problem to what you seem to require, so that should be adaptable to your needs.

Comment: @egreg: Exactly.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Exactly? Is that an answer to "where"?

Comment: @egreg My apologies, it contains `Content`, and is written in the first code line: `\long\def\FourierIntroduction{Content}`. Of course, I put more complex things in there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks pretty nice already. There are two things you missed.
First you need to expand `\csname` before `\def`. So take `\expandafter` and leave away the braces. Next the new command has to be available outside the current scope and also `\BODY` is only knowing at define time and thus has to be expanded there. So you have to use `\xdef` which is short for `\global\edef` instead of `\def`. All in all this means:

```
\NewEnviron{introduction}{%
  \expandafter\long\expandafter\xdef\csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname{\BODY}%
}%
```

will do what you need.

**More general solution:**

As the above version will make problems when `\BODY` is not fully expandable here is another try. It took me some effort, but I think the following will expand `\BODY` exactly one time and thus give you the correct result:

```
\NewEnviron{introduction}{%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\xdef\csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}%
}%
```

*A bit of explanation about the expansion:*

Let's assume that `\BODY` contains only `Some \textbf{text}` for simplicity, which would also trigger the problem in the first try. So now we have

```
\expandafter\long\expandafter\xdef\csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}
```

The first two `\expandafter` make `TeX` step forward to the `\csname`-`\endcsname` construction and expand that, so that we get

```
\long\xdef{FourierIntroduction}{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}
```

Now `\xdef` tries to expand the whole second argument and is here only inhibited by `\unexpanded`. Those remaining two `\expandafter` mean `TeX` jumps over `\unexpanded` and `{` to first expand `\BODY` (one time) and leave

```
\long\xdef{FourierIntroduction}{\unexpanded{Some \textbf{text}}}
```

So this is the point at which `\xdef` eats the `\unexpanded` and does not expand the argument of `\unexpanded` (the content of `\BODY`) any further; leaving something like

```
\long\global\def{FourierIntroduction}{Some \textbf{text}}
```

Comment: Excellent! This works. My savior on my birthday :-). However, when I try to put some environment inside the `introduction` environment like something of `amsthm`. I get the error: `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 6.` Would you know what causes this? Line 6 is after the `\usepackage{environ}`.

Comment: I have added this to the original message. Thanks! :-).

Comment: Perfect. This works splendidly! :-). Now I should try to understand how this expansion works in TeX... Seems to be quite peculiar.