# Where to locate careers in TeX?

Tags: tex-general

I already know InDesign but am considering learning TeX. Right now I work in publishing laying out books and magazines but I love typography, English and precision and want to switch to a marketing coordinator position involving RFQ/RFP/Proposal/Bid writing and layout.

That's where I could see TeX being very handy in formatting a 10-20 page proposal and all of the employee qualifications. But when I search for say "Marketing Latex" I only find things on Marketing Latex Paints. Where if I search "Marketing InDesign" I get fairly precise jobs I could be looking into.

Before I set out to learn TeX, how does one go about searching for careers to gauge the market? Is there a particular term I should try? Latex Operator didn't find anything related either.

Comment: One suggestion I have if you are unable to locate a career involving TeX is to start your own business. If you have a brilliant idea that involves TeX, go for it!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think you will not find any jobs that have a specific TeX requirement. TeX is very common among academic users and technical writers, but not very common among marketing or design companies. The only big exception is book publishers, especially those who publish technical books, such as O'Reilly. If you want to look for jobs in that industry, use the respective keywords.

If you want to dive deeper and find out more about LaTeX in use, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40720/latex-in-industry) on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think their is also a market for automatic document generation. LaTeX is sometimes used as a tool at webservers to generate pdfs. For instance some websites send PDFs through email, or Wikipedia where a user can generate a book. Some of these PDFs are generated by scripts: some PHP code writes LaTeX code and then calls the LaTeX compiler.

Comment: @Martin Betz - I'm not looking at Design/Marketing companies. I'm looking for RFP/RFQ writing which are technical documents used for the government bid process. I didn't even include publishing tag, someone edited that in.

Comment: Found this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/is-anybody-using-tex-for-business-reporting which seems to indicate people do it but only after already getting into a company and convincing the organization to let them

Comment: @Ryan Okay, then use these keywords for searching for companies that work in that area. Then ask them directly whether or not they work with LaTeX. And post your answers here for reference.

Comment: Well thats my problem Martin. I tried that and all I got were jobs related to latex paints. Hence the question. If I do find anything I will but was hoping someone might know a better way as "Tex" and "Latex" are not the most distinct terms to try searching for.

Comment: Well, as said, rather go for companies that work in this section. Try leaving out TeX keywords. Instead look through the job descriptions that you find and ask the companies directly. Alternatively, you can use the powerful `-` search feature in Google. You can filter out thing you don't want to see: `-paint` and the like...