# Are there any organizations which use LaTeX for preparing their documents, other than universities?

Tags: latex-misc, tex-general

TeX and LaTeX are widely used in academic disciplines. Are there other organizations which use LaTeX for preparing their documents?

Since it is easy to create LaTeX files with scripts, it is a good idea to prepare documents such as annual reports using LaTeX. But I don’t know any organization that uses LaTeX!

Comment: Does Oracle count? [Here's an example document](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/UserManual.pdf).

Comment: Possibly related: [Is anybody using TeX for business reporting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/is-anybody-using-tex-for-business-reporting)

Comment: [Here](http://www.antisway-lehnert.com/de/ueber-uns/jobs.html) I found a job posting (in German) which asks for good MS Office skills AND LaTeX.

Comment: Someone told me that Sas uses LaTeX for its technical manuals but I don't have a reliable source.

Comment: Every project using [Texinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo) for documentation is using TeX.  This includes basically all [GNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Project) projects.

Comment: Adding to @CarLaTeX's gossip, I heard that BMW does ask for engineers with LaTeX-skills (no source either).

Comment: Yes they are. I'm working for some of them ... (but naturally can't give names).

Comment: Wikipedia's PDF article printing uses TeX and friends.

Comment: Some of us used it unofficially when I was working for Exxon (which was how I was exposed in the first place).

Comment: I used LaTeX at the Boeing Airplane Company for technical reports, code documentation, etc. Also ISO (International Standards Organization) uses LaTeX. I have also used LaTeX at GE and NIST.

Comment: The [C++ Standard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) is typeset in LaTeX.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/940 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40720

Comment: yep, @CarLaTeX is right, I work at SAS and produce a lot of the analytical product documentation using LaTeX and some customization (class/packages).

Comment: @TimA Happy to know that!

Comment: Should this be marked as Community Wiki?

Comment: Vecna, a robotics company in Cambridge, MA, uses LaTeX to prepare their grant proposals.

Comment: My organization, https://www.arl.army.mil/, allows authors to use either LaTeX or Word approaches for producing organizational technical reports.  While most are still done via Word, and increasing number now are created via LaTeX.  I am the author and maintainer of my organization's `\documentclass` and report stencil.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, we do.
AIL Auto-Interleasing AG (Switzerland) is using a self programmed software that makes all the invoiceses to be sent to customers. For this I use LaTeX templates that get enriched and finally produce pdflatex.
Cool stuff!